# How do I align something in a <td> in the top-left corner - without aligning everything?

Tags: html, css

Say I have something that looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Dtsjh/

How do I align the numbers in each cell to be in the top-left corner of each cell - without aligning the words?

Preferably in just HTML/CSS - but if you can't do it any of those, then jQuery is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the number in a `<span>`, float it to the left, and give it a negative top margin to push it up into the corner: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/chp8y/

You'll have to fiddle with the pixel values on the `.sit-in-the-corner` margins to get something that works for you.

Answer (score 8):

```
td {
vertical-align: top;
text-align: left;
}
```

put the above css for the row of the table..And it works.
If you want specific to that td, put the id of the td in css.

Comment: A great document of [vertical-align](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) i want to share.

Answer (score 1):

In the TD tag you can use the align="left".  Inside of the style attribute you can also try and add a horizontal alignment or text-alignment:left.   Try to add a div, and a span inside a div for some more complex alignment with the style attribute  style="text-align:left;".

see link: [link text](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_text-align.asp)

Comment: Conversely you can try and add either divs and spans with padding, or just add another table inside the td tag.